# I am making rating slider(carousel) dynamic but all are my records are coming vertically

Tags: laravel

```
<div class="container mt-4 mb-4 gfg" style ="background-color: #f6f6f6">
        @if(!empty(count($homeData)))
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                <h3 class="text-center text-color font-weight-bold" style = "margin-top :10px">What Are Others Saying ?</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row blog">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="blogCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#blogCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#blogCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        </ol>


                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <div class="row">
                                    @foreach($reviews as $review)
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <a>
                                                <div class="home1-img mt-3">
                                                    <?php 
                                                        for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
                                                            $check = '';
                                                            if($review->number_of_stars >= $i){
                                                                $check = 'checked';
                                                            }
                                                            echo '<span class="fa fa-star '.$check.'"></span>';
                                                        }
                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="home1-text mt-1" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                                                        <p>{!! Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($review->customer_review,100) !!}</p>
                                                        <h5 class="text-color font-weight-bold">{{ $review->customer_name }}</h5>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach                     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                    
                            <!--.item-->

                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endif
</div>
```

I am making rating slider(carousel) dynamic but all are my records are coming vertically but I want 3 records should come then in another slide three slider should come and so on. I have tried but records are coming vertically only.

Comment: can you show the controller??

Comment: $reviews = CustomerReview::all();

Comment: return view('viewName', compact('reviews'));

Comment: this is because you are only defining a single item for carousel and inside that you are looping the reviews. so all your reviews are coming in a single slide.

Comment: Any idea about that what I can do for that?

Comment: in a single slide you want to show 3 items and make 3 sildes for 9 items (just a number). right?? you have to break down your reviews.

Comment: Yes I have also done that but it doesn't work:-)

Comment: added an example answer for you..check that out..

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, you have only one single slide and all your data is in that slide. you have to break the reviews in a chunk and loop over. take a look at the collection [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-chunk) method.

```
<div class="row blog">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="blogCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                @foreach ($reviews->chunk(3) as $key => $reviewList)
                    <li data-target="#blogCarousel" data-slide-to="{{ $key }}" @if ($key == 0) class="active" @endif></li>
                @endforeach
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                @foreach ($reviews->chunk(3) as $key => $reviewList)
                    <div @if ($key == 0) class="item active" @else class="item" @endif>
                        <div class="row">
                            @foreach ($reviewList as $review)
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <a>
                                        <div class="home1-img mt-3">
                                            @php 
                                                for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
                                                    $check = '';
                                                    if ($review->number_of_stars >= $i) {
                                                        $check = 'checked';
                                                    }
                                                    echo '<span class="fa fa-star '.$check.'"></span>';
                                                }
                                            @endphp
                                            <div class="home1-text mt-1" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                                                <p>{!! Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($review->customer_review,100) !!}</p>
                                                <h5 class="text-color font-weight-bold">{{ $review->customer_name }}</h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach                     
            </div>
        </div>    
     </div>
 </div>
```

this should give you the idea of how to do it. adjust according to your need if necessasry.

Comment: In 1 slide 12 records are coming but I want that 3 records should come and then automatic slider should start.

Comment: do you make the chunk as i said?? look closely to my code. you should get an idea of how to do that.